# Is it possible to export a Sharepoint site to a format that another Wiki can use?

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, export

I am trying to export from Sharepoint to Confluence. When I use the `Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate` command I get XML that seems very SharePoint specific. The same can be said for the HTML source of any SP page.

I was wondering if there is a way to use Sharepoint's API to extract the data from a site in a format that is readable by other Wikis?

Comment: Hi. Command `Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate` will export/create a template based on site, not the data and content. As I understand, that is what You *are not* looking for. There are multiple ways how to retrieve data, it depends on other system that is receiving data - what format, type etc it can retrieve.. and please be more specific by saying "extract data" - do You want get data from some specific lists or document metadata in library or else?

Comment: Hey, I am attempting to export any files, pictures and text from the website. I do not need to maintain any styling. You are right that Get-PnpProvisioningTemplate is not right for this. I just am really new to this. The format would preferably be HTML, but really anything would be better than nothing. I am currently trying to export images and files using the Python Library BeautifulSoup. Thanks for replying, I know I'm probably not making much sense.

Comment: Since Your requirements for migration are quite broad and general, I would suggest to look for already available solutions that are handling *migration from Sharepoint to Confluence*. I cannot give You exact vendors, but try googling and You will find many options. If You want to do this job Yourself, I would advise to look more into Confluence side of integrations and APIs - how to create data from code (that could be more complex than retrieving data from SharePoint).

Comment: Okay. Thank you. :)